# Выборка по диапазону дат и по первой строке до и после диапазона

Tags: sql, sql-server

Имеется запрос вида:

```
SELECT * FROM [table] WHERE [ControlDate] <= '2019-05-29T16:00:02.000' ORDER BY [ControlDate]
```

Теперь нужно сделать так, чтобы в выборку попадала еще одна строка, идущая следующей после последней в исходной выборке..
То есть получить её можно так:

```
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM [table] WHERE [ControlDate] > '2019-05-29T16:00:02.000' ORDER BY [ControlDate]
```

Но это заставляет выполнять 2 запроса, а хотелось бы оптимизировать так, чтобы конечный результат получался после выполнения одного.

Вариант с union рассматривал, но тоже не нравится. Оператор `LEAD` в условии использовать нельзя(

Может есть еще варианты? Благодарю.

Answer (score 0):

```
with cte as
(select *, row_number() over(order by ControlDate) rn from [table]),
rownum as
(select max(rn)+1 rn1 from cte where ControlDate ='2019-05-29T16:00:02.000')
select cte.* from cte, rownum where rn<=rn1;
```